# Spring autowire null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, datasource, javabeans, autowired

xml configuration -

```
<bean id="DS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${DB.DRIVERCLASS}" />
        <property name="url" value="${TABLEMAINT.URL}" />       
        <property name="username" value="${TABLEMAINT.USER}" />
        <property name="password" value="${TABLEMAINT.PASSWORD}" />
    </bean>

@Component
class AbcDAO{
 @Autowired
private DriverManagerDataSource DS;
   public void getConnection(){
      System.out.println("DS - "+DS..getConnection());
   }
}
```

datasource DS.getConnection getting null pointer exception.

Autowiring not working.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Read the Java naming convention. Property names should start with lower case character so your "DS" must be "ds"

Comment: @pvpkiran no. it's my dao class

Comment: How you instanciate the class ABS? Is it a spring managed bean?

Comment: Yes.. I haven't copied full code here

Comment: Add the related code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABC is not managed by spring.

For @Autowired annotation to work you have to annotate that class with either of the following:

```
@Component
@Service
@Controller
@Repository
```

or define it in the XML configuration

Comment: which one I should use from these?

Comment: IT's not my controller or service class

Comment: @yuvaツ is it a repository? if not use '@Component'

Comment: No. Tried with component also.. not working

Comment: see code updated..

Comment: then you are using the AbcDao wrong. Where do you autowire it into? post controller/service code.

Comment: Is it neccessory to autowire my DAO class also?

Comment: yes, of course. Else it wouldn't be managed by Spring

Comment: Thank you so much.. It's working now :)